Generalized restricted Nim with one pile
Source: Leetcode 292: Nim Game
Background
The statement problem (from the original problem linked at the top) is as follows:

You are playing the following Nim Game with your friend:

Initially, there is a heap of stones on the table.
You and your friend will alternate taking turns, and you go first.
On each turn, the person whose turn it is will remove 1 to 3 stones from the heap.
The one who removes the last stone is the winner.

Given n, the number of stones in the heap, return true if you can win the game assuming both you and your friend play optimally, otherwise return false.

The following test cases are given:

Input: n = 4
Output: False

Input: n = 1
Output: True

Input: n = 2
Output: True


This was admittedly pretty difficult at first, because it was pretty difficult to check individual test cases for perfect play. However I ended up finding this Math Stack Exchange post going over the same thing, but for taking up to 2 stones from the pile at a time.
Luckily, I was able to implement this strategy for the case, $n=3$, seeing that the first false case was when the number of stones was equal to 4:
# Python 3.8
class Solution:
    def canWinNim(self, n: int) -> bool:
        if n%4!=0:
            return True
        else: return False

Which turned out to be 100% correct.

Question and thinking
However, what I want to know is: What happens when each player can take up to $n$ stones in a pile of $k$ stones, and what's the strategy assuming optimal play?
Here's my thinking:

Obviously if $k\le n$, then Player 1 has a winning strategy - just taking the $k$ stones in the pile.
If $k=n+1$, and actually if $k\equiv0\pmod{(n+1)}$, then Player 2 has a winning strategy.

Since $k\equiv0\pmod{(n+1)}$, then if Player 1 takes $x$ stones, then Player 2 can take $n+1-x$ stones, regardless of $x$. Player 2 then rinses and repeats until done.



Now I know that Player 1 has a winning strategy when $k\gt n$ and $k\not\equiv0\pmod{(n+1)}$. However, my question is: What is the strategy in this case?

The winning strategy is "take as many stones as needed to reduce the pile to $0 \bmod (n+1)$." Repeat until $k \le n$.
Proof that it's a good strategy: after your move, your opponent will NOT be in the situation described in your final paragraph, but after any move your opponent makes, you WILL be. By (reverse) induction, that's a winner.
